# Apache load balancer won't forward to second balance member

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, httpd.conf

I'm trying to figure out what is wrong with my apache config that is preventing the balancer from calling the second BalanceMember on port 9001. Or even some kind of troubleshooting options. Apache logs are bare.

Using the configuration below apache starts normally and requests are forwarded from 80 to 9000 as expected. However when I shut down the service running on 9000 the service running on 9001 is not called on a request to port 80. I can get to the service running on 9001 directly so i know for sure that it is running and available.

```
   <VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
    ServerName myportal.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/drig/data/www/myportal.com
    SuexecUserGroup drig drig

ProxyStatus on
ProxyPreserveHost on

    <Location /balancer-manager>
            SetHandler balancer-manager

            Order Deny,Allow
            Allow from all

    </Location>

    <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
            BalancerMember http://localhost:9000
            BalancerMember http://localhost:9001 status=+H
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
    ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: try remove `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/` and `ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9001/`

Comment: Tried it. No luck. Same response. I've also added ProxyStatus on but dont know how to query out the proxy info from the server

Comment: Ok, you need the same configuration on vhost https, try remove `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on RewriteRule /(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1`  for testing purpose

Comment: Tried that. Still no luck. I have edited by answer with the simplified configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being iptables blocking the connection. This was running on an EC2 instance and when I ran:

```
service iptables stop
```

The connection was successful with the configuration above.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyRequests off     
        ServerName myportal.com

        <Proxy balancer://mycluster>
                BalancerMember http://localhost:9000
                BalancerMember http://localhost:9001

                Order Deny,Allow
                Deny from none
                ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
        </Proxy>

        <Location /balancer-manager>
                SetHandler balancer-manager
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Location>

        ProxyPass /balancer-manager !
        ProxyPass / balancer://mycluster/

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Still no luck. Same setup. I turned debug on in apache and this is all i get:
    [Fri Jan 30 18:21:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1863):   proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
    [Fri Jan 30 18:21:40 2015] [debug] proxy_util.c(1960): proxy: initialized single connection worker 4 in child 8489 for (*)